# What can I do to get a better fit to my data?

Tags: fitting

I have started quite recently to use Mathematica and i found a problem, I'm trying to fit a function to my data, but i can't find the best fit around the minimum values (around 3.14).

```
w1 = 2.8602
w2 = 3.4209;
```

The model used here is

```
model = (a b/(b^2 + (t - w1)^2)) + (c d/(d^2 + (t - w2)^2))
result = 
  NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {a, b, c, d}, t, 
    MaxIterations -> 800, Method -> {NMinimize}]
```

The model above should fit my data:

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/a9mjfhc409fdu9nqw5l8g/data.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=bdvvzp819f2ntfuktg2g466fh

which gives

[image]

Any ideas ?

Comment: The data you've posted is incomplete. Try using the backticks ``` ` ``` to delimit the code block in your question instead of four spaces.

Comment: The data given is incomplete.  It ends with `{2.7093, 0.3385}, {2.7103,`.  And about two-thirds into the data is `{2.6553 0.206}` (i.e., a comma is missing and *Mathematica* multiplies the two number leaving you with just a single number rather than a list with two numbers).

Comment: Thank you for your remarks, i updated my data.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that the model is not complex enough to adequately describe the data.  *Mathematica* functions are working just fine.

Your data is fairly symmetric around 3.14 and without much loss of generality the model

```
model2 = (a b/(b^2 + (t - w1)^2)) + (a b/(b^2 + (t - w2)^2))
```

produces a function nearly identical to the original model locking in the symmetry.

If values of `b` are chosen to get the function values near zero for `t` around 3.14, this results in a poor fit.  Again, you really only have 2 parameters, `a` and `b` if you want to keep the symmetry.  Using `Manipulate` you can convince yourself that the model is inadequate for your data:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red], 
  Plot[(a b)/(b^2 + (-3.4209` + t)^2) + (a b)/(
    b^2 + (-2.8602` + t)^2), {t, 2.5, 4}, PlotRange -> All]],
 {{a, 0.08}, 0, 0.2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 0.08}, 0, 0.2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {a, b}]
```

[image: Selection of a and b to get values near zero for t around 3.14]

You need a more complex model to obtain an adequate description of your data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used a model from the literature, which describes this kind of function. I will check if there are other complex models.

Comment: @Adam just as a general suggestion, you might find that you need to add to your model another function with separate parameters which helps to better define the curvature you want to fit to.